# PHP 7.3 not installing on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, php

I am trying to install php 7.3 over ubuntu 16.04. but its always shows

```
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.3
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.3'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.3'
```

i have tried everything available over net like following

```
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

this also

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

with sudo access.

```
sudo apt install php7.3 php7.3-common php7.3-cli
```

nothing is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you run `sudo apt update` yet?  If you haven't, your system isn't going to *know* that the PHP 7.3 packages are available.

Run `sudo apt update` and *then* try the install commands you were trying.

Comment: No it did not work either